# Hypothesis Testing: Z-test or T-test? and how to test the null hypothesis?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, self-study, t-test, computational-statistics

I have a question as below:

I have to generate two portfolio returns in R and compare their means.

However, I am not sure which test should be applied in this case. And how can I indicate at least 2% higher statement in the null hypothesis. I wrote this code:

```
asset1 <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)
asset2 <- rnorm(100, 0.1, 1)
z.test(asset1, asset2, mu = 0.02, alternative = "greater", sigma.x = 1, sigma.y = 1)
```

I am not so sure about this code because I wrote mu = 0.02 but there should be an appropriate way to show the difference in means is at least higher than 2% of the mean of the first population. Furthermore, since I thought that I have the true population parameters here, I applied Z test and set sigma.x and sigma.y to 1, but is this the correct way to proceed?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Please add the self-study tag (in place of mathematical statistics) and read its wiki. A good place to start would be saying why you selected the parameters you did in z.test and why you’re not sure about them.

Comment: I also recommend putting set.seed(2020) at the top of your code so that you can reproduce your results.

Comment: Thank you. I added extra information regarding your suggestions.

Comment: As a final clarification, are the “returns” supposed to be percent return and you’re just supposed to test if $\mu_1-\mu_2>0.02?$

Comment: Yes, that was what I understood.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the unequal variance t-test (default t.test in R) here, and I think the full-credit answer would go through why you elected against z-testing and equal-variance t-testing even though you know the variances and know that they’re equal.

The reason why I’d go with t over z is that, yes, you know the population standard deviations, but you also know the population means! If you’re going to take the simulation parameters as known, there’s no hypothesis testing to do. You know, with *certainty*, that the first asset has lower average returns than the second. If you don’t know that, then you shouldn’t be able to say that you know the standard deviations.

Put another way, if your teacher just gave you two data sets that she generated form your code, but you did not know the generation process, you would proceed with an unequal-variance t-test (aka Welch’s t-test).

Comment: Thank you! That made sense now.